# On locally complete intersection subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let, $Y$ be a closed subscheme of a nonsingular variety $X/ \mathbb C$. We say that $Y$ is a local complete intersection in $X$ if the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_Y$ of $Y $ in $X$ can be locally generated by $ r = \operatorname{Codim} (Y ,X)$ elements at every point.

At this point my questions are the following :

$(1)$ What is the precise meaning of the statement "....can be locally generated by $r$ elements " ? Does it mean for every point $y \in Y$ there exists an affine open neighbourhood $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ containing $y$ such that $\mathcal I_Y(\operatorname{Spec}A)$ is generated by $r$ elements as an ideal of $\mathcal O_Y(\operatorname{Spec}A)$ ?

$(2)$ Is it true that any $0$ dimensional closed subscheme  of $X$ is always a locally complete intersection? Or is there any special situation when this happens?

And I believe that the following statement "Every strict complete intersection is a locally complete intersection" is true like other similar concepts in Algebraic geometry. (please correct me if I am wrong)

Here strict complete intersection means (atleast in  projective space ) the   ideal $I(Y)$ is generated by $\operatorname{Codim} (Y)$ many elements.

Can someone give me a concrete example of a locally complete intersection subscheme ?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: 1. Please use \operatorname{Spec} to typeset $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it produces much better spacing. 2. You've omitted a definition of "strict complete intersection", which will resolve your (un-numbered) third question. 3. Have you made any efforts of your own to find a reference, like Googling? What did you like or not like about those references? What do you like or not like about referring to Hartshorne? If you can expand on that, you may get better suggestions for references.

Comment: For 1), your guess is correct. For the other questions, have you made any efforts of your own? I'd feel more comfortable helping you (and I think others would too) if you showed a little more of your thoughts here - if you're really interested in learning algebraic geometry, I think you need to put in some of your own efforts, and it would be irresponsible of me to disrupt your studies by letting you avoid that.